# Does value of docs.count in elasticsearch also include value of docs.deleted?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index with the following `docs.count` and `docs.deleted`.

```
docs.count   = 2762694
docs.deleted = 2508162
```

Is `docs.count` the total number of documents in disk including the ones marked as deleted? 
Or is the total number of documents in disk is `docs.count` + `docs.deleted`?

UPDATE: To clarify my concern, if `docs.count` also include the `docs.deleted` in it, then in the above example about 90% of the documents are deleted. But on the other hand the `docs.deleted` is not counted as part of `docs.count` and they are additional then only 47% of the documents are deleted. Based on this I can decide how important it is to use force merge.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The counts you see in the `_cat/indices` API response are counts at the Lucene level, so `docs.count` also includes hidden nested documents.

`docs.deleted` are indeed documents marked as deleted but not yet expunged.

If you want a real count of your documents you should use the `_cat/count` API which provides a clean count that indicates the number of live documents and does not include deleted documents which have not yet been cleaned up by the merge process.

Comment: yes, docs.count include hidden and nested document, but does it also contain deleted, specified by docs.deleted? I'll edit the question to make it clear.

Comment: No it doesn't include that number. Also note that `docs.deleted` doesn't necessarily mean that there are that many deleted documents, but the same document might have been updated/index/deleted several times.

Answer (score 3):

No. 
The `docs.count` does not include the `docs.deleted`.

`docs.deleted` are the documents that are marked for deletion by elasticsearch.

I don't know the exact operation you are performing but the `docs.deleted` can be this high even when you update a lot of your documents. As elasticsearch doesn't update the document in-place but deletes the older one and replaces it with the newer one.